# How to setup parity daemon

Tags: parity

I know parity can run as a daemon because the --help has a usage `parity daemon <pid-file> [options]` but no further help/clues/documentation is provided. What is `<pid-file>` ? A process ID file, and what is that? If it is supposed to be a systemd unit file why doesn't it say so.

The only other clue I can find after searching and searching is this:
https://daowiki.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DAO/Ethereum+network
It says to edit the parity.service and parity.conf file, however both of those do not exist. I can try creating them but then why is there NOTHING when googling on this. I can't be the first and only person on this planet to want to run parity as a daemon. (I don't want this question to sound negative. I really appreciate the great contribution the ethcore team and their parity project has given to the Ethereum community!)

Ubuntu 16.04
parity v1.2.2

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - it's just a path to an empty file of your choice, and prevents multiple instances of the daemon from running. (I don't *think* the file even needs to exist - it will be created for you.)

---

Parity uses the general Rust implementation of [`daemonize()`](https://github.com/knsd/daemonize/), which itself takes a `pid_file` argument.

Taking things one step further, the Rust implementation is based on Python's [daemonize library](https://github.com/thesharp/daemonize), which again uses the same idea.

The basic idea is to prevent multiple versions of your script/program running at the same time. Your `pid_file` argument is just a path to a file where the pid will be stored, which at first will be empty, but which will be written to by the running program.

- When the script starts, the first thing it does it look for a file (wherever you've put it - probably something like `/tmp/parity_daemon.pid`);
- If that file exists, then the script reads a pid from it. The script now checks if any process with that pid is already running. (Note that the pid file should be cleaned up when the daemon gracefully exits, but it's possible the daemon crashed on its last run, so the pid file still exists.);
- If there is a process running with that pid, then there is already a running instance of this program/daemon, so the new daemon instance should exit.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an init system (systemd, SysV, upstart) to manage the Parity process. Here I will provide an example using systemd, and additional resources are listed at the end.

---

First, define the service in a systemd unit file:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/parity.service
[Unit]
Description=Parity Ethereum client
Documentation=https://wiki.parity.io
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/parity
Restart=on-failure
# SIGHUP gives parity time to exit cleanly before SIGKILL
KillSignal=SIGHUP

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=parity.service
EOF
```

We want to avoid an unclean shutdown of the parity process, because that can cause database corruption. To accomplish this we override the default `KillSignal`, so `SIGHUP` (equivalent to ctrl-c) is sent first. After 90 seconds (by default), if the process is still running, then `SIGKILL` would be sent.

You may also want to modify the `ExecStart` parameter to include additional options.

After the service is defined we can reload the definitions from disk:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable the service, so it starts automatically after a reboot:

```
sudo systemctl enable parity
```

And, finally, start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start parity
```

Another thing to note is `Restart=on-failure`. This will automatically restart the process when it dies (including if you manually kill it).

To stop Parity, use:

```
sudo systemctl stop parity
```

To check the status, use:

```
systemctl status parity
```

You can also follow logs with `journald`:

```
journalctl -f -u parity.service
```

---

Note that init services provide a lot of flexibility, and this is only a simple example using systemd, which is now the most common. For additional reading, visit these resources:

- **systemd**: [Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) (intro from Digital Ocean), and [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) (freedesktop.org)
- **SysVinit**: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SysVinit)
- **Upstart**: [Getting Started](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) from Ubuntu

Comment: don't forget to use `sudo loginctl enable-linger username` if using `systemctl --user enable /path/to/parity.service` to prevent stopping parity when user logs out

Comment: @thinkmassive I am using this solution because the parity docker solution was working but there were no folders getting created. So I did know where was all the chaindata, keys etc going. I used this solution and now Parity is working absolutely fine and I can also use geth to attach to the IPC service. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Anyone who is reading or implementing this example please do not include the `Alias=parity.service` as the second last line. It causes problems while enabling the service. Rest everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the use case of daemon is similar to `screen`, I am just suggesting another approach of running parity in background.

- Start a new screen using `screen -s parity`. Here the name of the screen is `parity`.
- Start the parity in the usual way you start as.
- `Ctrl+A Ctrl+D` to detach from screen, parity still runs in background. Even if you logout from server, screen is running and you can come back and visit the screen anytime.
- You can `resume` the screen using `screen -r`
- `screen -ls` to see all screens.